# Is "Marco Polo" slang?

Tags: slang

I have heard some people utter "Marco Polo" in distress or shocking cases. Is it slang? Or is it used as something else? 
Can someone great as Marco Polo be used as an abusive word?

Comment: were they trying to find somebody, or pretending they couldn't find somebody? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marco_Polo_(game)

Comment: Perhaps it's used (regionally?) as a substitute for a more offensive expletive such as "Jesus H. Christ!"

Comment: @Kristina: _Richard M. Nixon!_ I'm with you. Many folks find traditional expletives offensive for some reason, so they use less a common one, or invent their own – one that might be much less likely to offend. I remember when my Dad was exasperated, he'd sometimes mutter, "Sacramento, California." I think he just liked the rhythm of the syllables. Anyway, back to the O.P.'s question: **any** name can be used as an "abusive word," I think; it's more related to the tone of the speaker than the person behind the name.

Comment: It _may_ be used as a polite alternative to _motherf...er_. Just a shot in the dark but the rhythm of the two is similar.

Comment: @terdon: Not to mention the alliteration. I like that theory.

Comment: @J.R. Your Dad might also have been influenced by the fact that Sacramento is named after the Holy Sacrament and sometimes called Sacred City.

Comment: Other examples of names acceptably taken in vain are "[Jiminy Cricket!](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=jiminy%20cricket)" and "[Judas Priest!](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Judas_Priest)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, to my knowledge it is neither slang as such nor offensive in any way. One possibility is that *Marco Polo* is being used as a substitute for *Motherfu..er*. The rhythm is similar and *Marco* is close enough to *Mother* to give it a nice alliterative ring.

I have never heard it used this way and it is definitely neither offensive nor vulgar. However, if you have heard people use it as an expletive, they are probably using it because it is an alliteration of the other word. Think of it as an equivalent to words like *darn* or *drat* replacing *damn*.

Comment: While that's a reasonable assumption, even if that's what the speaker intends, to answer the OP's question, "Marco Polo" is *not* slang or abusive language.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of an [unusual euphemism](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UnusualEuphemism) (warning: tvtropes).

Over time, euphemisms tend to pick up vulgar connotations of their own, a phenomenon called the [euphemism treadmill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism#Evolution). For example, [*toilet*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=toilet) was once an innocent word meaning “a dressing room” (1819) but eventually became a euphemism for “lavatory or porcelain plumbing fixture” (1895). Now, *toilet* is itself a vulgar word, replaced in polite company with other euphemisms like *restroom* (1899) or *powder room* (1936).

To avoid the appearance of impropriety, people often use idiosyncratic euphemisms instead of established ones. That appears to be the case for *Marco Polo!* here, which does not turn up in Google searches for euphemisms or expletives. As others have noted, it has a similar cadence to *Motherf—er!* (or perhaps *Jesus Christ!*), much like the minced oath *Cheese and Rice!*

Because the whole point of an unusual euphemism is to use an entirely innocent word (which expresses vulgarity only by context), you needn't worry about people misunderstanding *Marco Polo* in other contexts.

Comment: If you wanna quote tvtropes, let's add [this one](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GoshdangItToHeck), quite relevant to the original question, if I may.

Answer (score -2):

Originally the explorer Marco Polo was separated from his family while traveling in China.

His family would yell "Marco" to get him and he would shout "Polo" back.

This somehow developed in a game in a swimming pool.

It has NO OTHER meaning, not vulgar nor abusive.

Comment: Interestingly, a similar explanation attaches to the paradox inventor Zeno, who accompanied a Greek mercenary army on its travels through Persia and points north. Every time someone tried to reach him by landline (this being before cell phones were invented), his parents would find themselves calling out, "Zeno! Phone!" And that's how the author of _Anabasis_ got his nom de plume.

Answer (score -3):

The word Marco Polo is not a slang word people utter it when they are looking for something and can't find it.

Comment: This is the first time I've encountered it in any context other than as a person's name. Can you please expand your answer explain when, where, why, how it is used in this manner? And preferably also it's derivation.

Comment: Sam, so Anglophones, differently from Italians, don't use "[Pluto](https://www2.bc.edu/alaina-beyar/images/pluto.jpg)" in that context?

Comment: @Carlo_R. I don't understand your meaning nor your link to a cartoon dog - but no we don't! "Pluto" is a planet.

Comment: @TrevorD, Pluto is no longer a planet...http://www.universetoday.com/13573/why-pluto-is-no-longer-a-planet/ ...but it *is* Mickey Mouse's dog. The times they change, don't they? :-)

Comment: @Kristina, great comment! In Italian one would say "Hai preso due piccioni con una fava", but I cannot imagine the English translation :)

Comment: @Carlo_R., we say "killing two birds with one stone" hee hee! ;-)

Comment: @TrevorD [Marco Polo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marco_Polo_(game)) is a variant of tag played in a swimming pool. The player who is “it” plays blind, finding the other players by yelling “Marco!” to which everyone else must respond “Polo!”

Comment: @KristinaLopez Pluto was never a planet.  The definition of "*planet*" was imprecise for a while.   (Yes, I see your link, but they only supply pedantry in one subject.)